# Swift, AsyncThrowingStream causes tiny memory leak with OS Logger

Tags: swift, async-await, memory-leaks

While using leaks instrument that comes with Xcode to health check my AsyncThrowingStream, I noticed a tiny memory leak caused by invoking the logger in the catch block:

```swift
    private lazy var stream: AsyncThrowingStream<SomeData, Error> = {
        AsyncThrowingStream<SomeData, Error> { [weak self] continuation in
            guard let self else { return }
            self.continuation = continuation
            streamTask = Task {
                var isAlive = true
                while isAlive && self.task?.closeCode == .invalid {
                    do {
                        if let message = try await self.task?.receive() {
                            Self.logger.trace("\(SocketStrings.streamMessageYielded())")
                            if let socketData = SocketMessageMapper.map(message) {
                                self.track(socketData)
                                continuation.yield(socketData)
                            }
                        } else {
                            throw APIError.genericError
                        }
                    } catch {
                        Self.logger.critical("\(SocketStrings.streamMessageNotReceived(error.localizedDescription))")
                        continuation.finish(throwing: error)
                        isAlive = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }()
```

Line where the Leak instrument detects the leak:

```swift
...
} catch {
    Self.logger.critical("\(SocketStrings.streamMessageNotReceived(error.localizedDescription))")
...
```

It also says the leak is of 1 byte size so its tiny but I don't understand why is it happening in the first place.

This post here is to ask why is this happening to understand a bit more about memory management

Comment: I presume if you comment out the logging, that it goes away? Or what if you replace your logger with `Logger(.disabled)`. If the problem goes away, you probably shouldn’t worry about it. We have a long history of these negligible leaks being reported by framework API.

Comment: If you forgive a few unrelated observations, see https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/4d4f11c004473b0191273666fc7c2569.